# Latest Update appeared to block my DNS lookup

Tags: updates, dns

On installing latest Ubuntu update, my computer's ability to do DNS lookups was lost.  Firefox was useless, but TOR was able to connect and enabled figuring out how to back out the last update.  Ended up rebooting, and selecting the previous system from among the options.  Wow.  My mail went down, browser was down, `ping 4.2.2.2` was down, everything was down except TOR.  How does that work?  And it was a gradual development.

First, ping became useless (and sendemail), then the browser, and finally my email app when I rebooted using the latest update.  Here's the list of packages.  Couldn't figure out which was at fault:

```
Start-Date: 2017-04-18  07:22:25
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.793'
Upgrade: libdns-export162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), bind9-host:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), dnsutils:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), dnsmasq-base:amd64 (2.75-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.75-1ubuntu0.16.04.2), libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), ntpdate:amd64 (1:4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3, 1:4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.4), libisc-export160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6), libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.5, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.6)
End-Date: 2017-04-18  07:22:34
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `traceroute 8.8.8.8`? Or if you don't have that installed, `tracepath 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Thank you for the edits Mr. Kent.  A new set of system updates arrived a day or two later, and their installation appeared to have fixed the problem.